# Impulse response using partial fraction in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

If a given digital filter has transfer function polynomial coefficients
`Num = [1 2 1 2]` and `Den = [1 -1 0.5 -0.3]`
and I'm asked to find its impulse response using partial fraction method

I used this function `residuez(Num,Den)` and then directly plotted its output. Is this right or there is something missing.

My code is:

```
num = [1 2 1 2];  
Den = [1 -1 0.5 -0.3];  
figure  
stem(residuez(num,Den))
```

And the output figure is:
[image]

Comment: Could you share your code with us and the error message if any?

Comment: I've added my code and the output figure

Comment: But what is the question exactly? Btw I have a different output figure, with the exact same code.

Comment: Are these the coefficients for a causal filter, or which samples do your coefficients apply to?